# ReadAsAsync<T>,Expecting element from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/",Encountered 'Element' with name 'workflow', namespace ''

Tags: wcf, rest, serialization, xml-serialization, httpclient

I am trying to consume a REST API to Get data by httpclient, encountered a parsing problem ,{"Error in line 1 position 95. Expecting element 'workflow' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'workflow', namespace ''. "}

the client code is

```
string baseUri = "/rest/workflows/";
            client = CreateClient(baseUri);

            HttpRequestMessage request = CreateRequest(baseUri);
            var task = client.SendAsync(request);
            HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            response.Content.ReadAsAsync<collection>().ContinueWith(wf =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(wf.Result.workflow.Length);
                });
```

the data classes

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class collection
{

    private workflow[] workflowField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("workflow", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public workflow[] workflow
    {
        get
        {
            return this.workflowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.workflowField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and the response xml file is in this format

```
<collection xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <workflow uuid="5ffbde8c-c430-4851-9c83-164c102a4d68">
        <name>Remove a Volume</name>
        <categories>
            <category>Decommissioning</category>
        </categories>
    </workflow>
  </collection>
```

I can get the string by using  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and save it to xml file, then ,i deserilize it to collection,can succeed ,but need and a default namespace to the serizliazer

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(collection), "xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"");
            c = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as collection;
```

anyone can help on this

Answer (score 4):

You should not touch the generated file from xsd.exe tool.

Just explicitly set that you want to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of the `DataContractSerializer` used by default with `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` by setting `UseXmlSerializer = true`.

So you must create a specific type formatter like this :

```
var formatters = new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() {
                new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(){ UseXmlSerializer = true } };
```

And use it as a parameter of the `ReadAsAsync` method :

```
private async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
=> await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatters);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your namespaces do not match; your xml declares a *namespace alias* (`ns2`) for the atom address, but the namespace of the collection element is still empty, since it doesn't *use* that alias (it is not `ns2:collection`). Either the xml is wrong or the code is. If the xml cannot be changed, then simply set the namespace on the `[XmlRoot(...)]` to be the empty string. If the C# is correct and the xml is wrong, then make it the namespace instead of an alias:

```
<collection xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <workflow uuid="5ffbde8c-c430-4851-9c83-164c102a4d68">
        <name>Remove a Volume</name>
        <categories>
            <category>Decommissioning</category>
        </categories>
    </workflow>
  </collection>
```

or identically:

```
<ns2:collection xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <workflow uuid="5ffbde8c-c430-4851-9c83-164c102a4d68">
        <name>Remove a Volume</name>
        <categories>
            <category>Decommissioning</category>
        </categories>
    </workflow>
  </ns2:collection>
```

Comment: thanks Gravell. 
the i can't change xml because it is reponse of a web api.

Comment: thanks Gravell. 
the i can't change xml because it is reponse of a web api.
still the same error when i remove the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom".
by exception message,I doult if this is because the default serilizer, DataContractSerializer, used by the client. it ignores the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" but  try to search 'http://schemas .datacontract.org/2004/07/' . i don't know if i can set a default namespace for the client , just like set it for xmlserilizer
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(collection), "xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"");

Comment: @XiangHe The POCO class you show is clearly intended for `XmlSerializer`, not `DataContractSerializer`. The class and the xml must match; currently they do not. One of them needs to change. If the xml must stay the same, then you have to change the POCO class to indicate the empty namespace rather than the atom namespace, i.e. remove the atom namespace from `[XmlRoot(...)]`

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue when reading data from my web api. What solved the issue for me is to decorate the class in the client with the [DataContract(Namespace="namespacefromyourwebapi")] attribute and for each property in your class decorate it with the [DataMember] attribute.